# Behavior of assignment expression invoked by ng-click within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm attempting to update my model using `ng-click` attached to a `<p>`.

I have no problem with an assignment expression *outside* of an `ng-repeat`, or with calling a scope method *inside* the `ng-repeat`. However, if I use an assignment *inside* the `ng-repeat`, it appears to be ignored. I don't see any messages reported in the Firefox console, but haven't tried setting breakpoints to see if the event is being fired.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test of ng-click</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.selected = "";
            $scope.defaultValue = "test";
            $scope.values = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

            $scope.doSelect = function(val) {
                $scope.selected = val;
            }
        }
        //]]>  

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
        <p>Selected = {{selected}}</p>
        <hr/>
        <p ng-click='selected = defaultValue'>Click me</p>
        <hr/>
        <p ng-repeat='value in values' ng-click='selected = value'>{{value}}</p>
        <hr/>
        <p ng-repeat='value in values' ng-click='doSelect(value)'>{{value}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uy9Ba/2/), if you prefer (along with a couple of earlier variants).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Directive ngRepeat creates a new scope for each iteration, so you need to reference your variables in parent scope.

Use `$parent.selected = value`, as in:

```html
<p ng-repeat='value in values' ng-click='$parent.selected = value'>{{value}}</p>
```

Note: Function call propagates due to prototypal inheritance.

If you want to learn more: [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#wiki-JSproto).

Comment: D'oh! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: +1. Although $parent will work, using an object for your model is the recommended approach (see my answer for more details).

Answer (score 21):

As @Stewie mentioned, $parent is one way to solve this issue.  However, the recommended ([by the Angular team](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m)) solution is to not define primitive properties on the $scope.  Rather, the $scope should reference your model.  Using references also avoids the issue (because primitive properties will not be created on the child scopes which hide/shadow the parent scope properties of the same name), and you don't have to remember when to use $parent:

HTML:

```html
<p>Selected = {{model.selected}}</p>
<hr/>
<p ng-click='model.selected = defaultValue'>Click me</p>
<hr/>
<p ng-repeat='value in values' ng-click='model.selected = value'>{{value}}</p>
<hr/>
<p ng-repeat='value in values' ng-click='doSelect(value)'>{{value}}</p>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$scope.model = { selected: ""};
...
$scope.doSelect = function (val) {
   $scope.model.selected = val;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/LsweT/).

I recently updated the wiki page that @Stewie mentioned to always recommend this approach.

Comment: +1 Agree. Using $parent always seems a bit hackish, even though the end result is the same. I don't even use it. Guess I was just a bit too lazy today to explain the '.'. Also, +1 for updating wiki.

Comment: Have to say that I consider creating a special "model" object more of a hack. And more likely to lead to errors in a complex page (from misspellings if nothing else). Personally, I think functions are the best solution to model updates (and also for the expressions in `ng-show` and the like).

Comment: @kdgregory "The purpose of the $scope is to *refer* to the model, not to *be* the model" (from the Angular team video mentioned by Mark). You can use any javascript object you want as a model, then link it from your scope.

Comment: I'm more than three years late to this party, but I feel like the distinction between the scope and the model is a very nice one to keep. For very simple use cases you might want to use the scope *as* the model, but in real-world applications, having them clearly separated is really useful.