# how to Hide the angular element based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating the custom directive for `input` validation. Here I checked the input length, if input length is zero, it will show the error and am not unable to if an input is filled with characters, I want to hide it.

**Here is my Code :**

```
app.directive("formValidate", function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<p>Please Fill this Field</p>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], function(value) {

            if (((value || '').toString()).length == 0) {
                var errorMessage = angular.element("<p class='error'>This field is requiured!</p>");
                errorMessage.insertAfter(elem);
                //$compile(errorMessage)(scope);
            } else {
                 // What to do??
            }
        })


   <input form-validate required md-no-asterisk ng-model="newEmployee.name" type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

Comment: you can use the "ng-show" parameter as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19021489/4603295

Comment: I want to get the class and remove the error class if the input length is greater than zero, how to do??

Comment: u want hide from controller???

Comment: No, I want to hide the <p> with use of class as specified in the angular element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide element using class then you can create a class with

```
display:none
```

property, and apply class using `ng-class`

But angular itself provides good directives called `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

ng-show or ng-hide will render DOM element but will just hide on condition satisfied. If you use `ng-if` it will not even render DOM until and unless the condition is satisfied.

```
if (((value || '').toString()).length == 0) {
   $scope.hasError = true;
}else{
//do whatever 
}
```

in HTML just use

```
<p ng-show="hasError">Your Error Msg</p>
```

There are so many other methods can be used to do the same.

Comment: it does not show any error while the value is equal to zero

Comment: Hi, Check if your variable is in the scope or not..?
Try Printing the value of the variable in HTML.

or try using this method it is working fine.

`<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<p ng-show="test.length ==0">Error</p>`

Comment: whether I want to define the scope of the directive?

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="test"> <p ng-show="test.length ==0">Error</p> This doesnt need a directive even...