# Button click doesn't work in table column

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table and I have added a button to the right corner of each value cell.I have also added ng-click but its not working whereas same piece of code does work for other button.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="singleConfig in allConfigDatabase | filter:searchParameter">
        <td>{{singleConfig.parameter}}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="updateButton">
                <button type="button" ng-click="confirmationForm=true;showBasicForm=true">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </button>
            </span>{{singleConfig.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you got any console error ? Can you give an exemple of one of theses button working ?

Comment: What its the database type and your version of angularjs ?

Comment: More details please...

Comment: I dont have any database connection for now and I am using angular 1.3.15

Comment: <button ng-click="confirmationForm=true;showBasicForm=true;addNewConfig()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>

Comment: @ABOS what kind of details do you want?

Comment: Can you create a plunker or something we can run and test? It is much easier to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388344/behavior-of-assignment-expression-invoked-by-ng-click-within-ng-repeat) for your question.

It seems like `ng-repeat` creates new scope, so you have to use:

```
$parent.confirmationForm = true;
```

In order to be more precise, you need to use $parent only on primitives, if you would try to change an object, it would work without usin $parent scope.